# Magento 2 Join table customer entity and customer address entity

Tags: magento2, database, customer, join, join-table

I am trying to join customer entity table and customer address entity table. I am getting error in below code.
What could be the issue

```
        $agency_name=$customerData->getDefaultShippingAddress()->getAgencyName();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();


        $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
        $customerTable = $resource->getTableName('customer_entity');

$customerObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Address\Collection');
$collection = $customerObj
             ->addAttributeToSelect('agency_name', 'customer_address_entity')
              ->addAttributeToFilter('agency_name',array('eq'=>$agency_name));
              //->load();

              $collection->getSelect()->join(['ct'=>$customerTable],'main_table.parent_id=ct.entity_id',[]);

$c_data=$collection->getData();
print_r($c_data);
```

Giving me error.Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because the **main_table** does not exist. If you debug, you can see in

> vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Collection/AbstractCollection.php

the line

```
$this->getConnection()->quoteIdentifier('e.' . $attribute),
```

You must use

```
$collection->getSelect()->join(['ct'=>$customerTable],'e.parent_id=ct.entity_id',[]);
```

After this, it is not advisable to use the object manager as you are using it. For that, you can use the independence injections of the classes

> Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection

and

> Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Address\Collection

directly in your construct.

Comment: great.worked.Small error and took time to figure out